# Selectize.js com Tags, recarregar chave e valor em formulário de edição

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, selectize.js

> [Postei a mesma dúvida no SO Gringo também](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138983/selectize-js-with-tags-reload-selected-keys-and-values-on-edit-form).

Estou fazendo um formulário de pesquisa (`action=GET`) em que um campo utiliza Selectize.js:

```
$("#selectize").each(function () {
        $(this).selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            valueField: 'AdvogadoId',
            labelField: 'Descricao',
            searchField: ['AdvogadoId', 'Descricao'],
            create: false,
            persist: false,
            preload: true,
            initUrl: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
            initData: true,
            load: function (query, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
                    type: 'GET',
                    error: function () {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        callback(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Com o formulário vazio, digito o nome e a sigla do advogado. Vem tudo preenchido corretamente. Ao submeter a pesquisa, os valores vão para o *back-end* corretamente, separados por vírgulas.

Quando o formulário é recarregado com os valores do `GET`, o que acontece é que cada tag aparece apenas com a sigla do advogado preenchida, sem o nome. Ao verificar as opções, as opções escolhidas aparecem apenas como a sigla, sendo que o correto seria "Sigla - Nome".

Tentei algumas soluções como [esta](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/366) (não funciona, além de ser complexa pro que eu preciso) e [esta](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/522) (não uso `data-data`: uso apenas os valores do formulário).

Existe alguma forma (preferencialmente performática) de carregar esses valores corretamente em cada tag selecionada em tela?

---

Código no Back-end:

```
    public JsonResult PesquisarJson(String termo = "")
    {
        // Aqui não é EF. É Dapper em cima de Oracle.
        using (var repositorio = new AdvogadoRepositorio())
        {
            var registros = repositorio.Condicao(a => a.DataSaida == null).OrdenarPor(a => a.AdvogadoId).Selecionar();
            return Json(registros.Select(a => new { AdvogadoId = a.AdvogadoId, Descricao = a.AdvogadoId + " - " + a.Nome }).ToList(), 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="selectize-control form-control selectize multi plugin-remove_button">
    <div class="selectize-input items not-full">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px; opacity: 1; position: relative; left: 0px;">
    </div>
    <div class="selectize-dropdown multi form-control selectize plugin-remove_button" style="display: none;">
        <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Resultado do Rest:

```
[
  {
    "AdvogadoId": "A1",
    "Descricao": "A1 - Fulano de Araujo"
  },
  {
    "AdvogadoId": "A2",
    "Descricao": "A2 - Beltrano de Lima"
  },
  {
    "AdvogadoId": "A3",
    "Descricao": "A3 - Ciclano da Silva"
  },
  {
    "AdvogadoId": "A4",
    "Descricao": "A4 - Herculano Junior"
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Mas como você deseja obter "Sigla - Nome" se o `valueField` só permite um único atributo? considerando que os nomes suas respectivas siglas estejam em banco de dados e possuam um `ID`, a solução seria pegar o `ID` e obter o nome e sigla dos registros selecionados via backend.

Comment: Você também poderia customizar a source da selectize para receber um array de value fields e concatenar os respectivos no formato desejado

Comment: Então, o desafio faz parte da pergunta. Gostaria que essas ideias virassem uma resposta.

Comment: Edita a pergunta com o código do seu controlador por gentileza, assim a resposta não fica genérica

Comment: @FelipeAssunção Feito.

Comment: @FelipeAssunção Coloquei mais informações. Veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre porque o `<input>` ao selecionar é preenchido com o `AdvogadoId` e não com `Descricao`, quando você seleciona por exemplo:

[image: selectize.js]

Isso que você "enxerga" (botão cinza com o x do lado) é na verdade é o "label" e não o valor do `<input>`, neste caso o label usa a `Descricao` e o input usa a `AdvogadoId` veja `valueField: 'AdvogadoId',`

A única maneira *"pratica"* que vejo de fazer como deseja seria isto e colocar o `valueField` também como `Descricao`:

```
 $("#selectize").each(function () {
    $(this).selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button'],
        valueField: 'Descricao', //Adicionar descrição aqui também
        labelField: 'Descricao',
        searchField: ['AdvogadoId', 'Descricao'],
        create: false,
        persist: false,
        preload: true,
        initUrl: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
        initData: true,
        load: function (query, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
                type: 'GET',
                error: function () {
                    callback();
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    callback(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Caso queria realmente enviar as ids (`AdvogadoId`) terá que na próxima página refazer a consulta usando os ids pra trazer novamente as descrições.

No entanto talvez possa usar `sessionStorage` junto a [API do Selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) pra manter os `options` e adiciona-los automaticamente, um exemplo:

```
$(function() {
    var target = $("#selectize");
    var keySession = "selectizeData2";

    var update = function(a,b) {
        var opts = this.options;
        setTimeout(function() {//Requer timeout
            var values = target.val().split(",");
            console.log(values);

            var list = [];
            for (var k in opts) {
                current = opts[k];
                if (values.indexOf(current.AdvogadoId) !== -1) {
                    list.push({ AdvogadoId: current.AdvogadoId, Descricao: current.Descricao });
                }
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(list));
            sessionStorage.setItem(keySession, JSON.stringify(list));
        }, 1);
    };

    var getTarget = function(selectize) {
        var data = sessionStorage.getItem(keySession);
        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(parsedData);
        if (parsedData) {
            for (var k in parsedData) {
                var current = parsedData[k];
                selectize.addOption([current]);
                selectize.addItem(current.AdvogadoId);
            }
        }
    };

    target.each(function () {
        var handler = $(this).selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            valueField: 'AdvogadoId', //Veja que mantive o ID como value
            labelField: 'Descricao',
            searchField: ['AdvogadoId', 'Descricao'],
            create: false,
            persist: false,
            preload: true,
            initUrl: "test.php",
            initData: true,
            "onItemAdd": update, //Adiciona o evento
            "onItemRemove": update, //Adiciona o evento
            load: function (query, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    error: function () {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        callback(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        getTarget(handler[0].selectize);
    });
});
```

Seguindo o exemplo do @Felipe também pode usar um pré-consulta (se bem que pra performance isso não parece uma boa quando aumentar o numero de clientes cadastrados), ficaria assim  (é necessário limpar o input primeiro porque se não o Selectize.js considera que as ids já existem):

```
$(function() {
    var target = $("#selectize");
    var currentValue = target.val();

    target.val("");

    target.each(function () {
        $(this).selectize({
            plugins: ['remove_button'],
            valueField: 'AdvogadoId',
            labelField: 'Descricao',
            searchField: ['AdvogadoId', 'Descricao'],
            create: false,
            persist: false,
            preload: true,
            initUrl: "test.php",
            initData: true,
            onInitialize: function() {
                var self = this;
                var value = "," + currentValue + ",";

                $.ajax({
                  url: "test.php",
                  type: 'GET',
                  success: function(res) {
                    res.forEach(function(existingOption) {
                        self.addOption(existingOption);
                        if (value.indexOf("," + existingOption.AdvogadoId + ",") !== -1) {
                            self.addItem(existingOption.AdvogadoId);
                        }
                    });
                  }
                });
            },
            load: function (query, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "test.php",
                    type: 'GET',
                    error: function () {
                        callback();
                    },
                    success: function (res) {
                        callback(res);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: De fato funciona, mas eu tenho que tratar a lógica no back-end, e não era bem isso que eu queria. Vou conceder a recompensa mas não vou aceitar a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver este problema você vai precisar fazer um fix utilizando o método `onInitialize` a solução não é bonita, mas resolve essa deficiência da library:

```js
$(this).selectize({
  plugins: ['remove_button'],
  valueField: 'Sigla',
  labelField: 'Nome',
  searchField: ['Sigla', 'Nome'],
  create: false,
  persist: false,
  preload: true,
  initUrl: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
  initData: true,
  load: function(query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
      type: 'GET',
      error: function() {
        callback();
      },
      success: function(res) {
        callback(res);
      }
    });
  },
  // Bugfix
  onInitialize: function() {

    var self = this;
    var value = self.getValue();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/Advogados/PesquisarJson/",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {

        res.forEach(function(existingOption) {
          self.addOption(existingOption);
          self.addItem(existingOption[self.settings.valueField]);
        });

        self.setValue(value);
        self.blur();
      }
    });

  }
});
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, esse código apenas cuida de como inserir os dados na DropDown, mas ele não troca as opções somente das siglas pelas opções "Sigla - Nome".

Comment: Ele atualiza a exibição por consequência :)

Comment: Então, mas não funcionou. Isso que eu quero dizer.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez a lógica do felipe "funciona", mas é provavel que você teria que alterar o back-end pra suportar a consulta vazia e por isto talvez não tenha funcionado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Aqui não funcionou. Seria legal termos um Fiddle pra testar isto.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez tem razão não funciona, só olhei a lógica, faltou o comparativo entre o getValue e os items no foreach